# Large Web Font (Yes or No?)

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use special font on my website, but the file is over 9 MB. Is it possible to reduce font's size? Thanks folks!

Comment: Programming or graphic design related? Not sure...

Comment: A font of over 9 MB??? It isn't a vector font, I suppose?

Comment: do you mean a Web Open Font Format?

Comment: @Glycerine: Not necessarily. Apart from font formats, like PostScript, TrueType and OpenType, you can categorize fonts in two ‘types’: [bitmap fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts) and [vector fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Outline_fonts). The former tend to give larger files than the latter. Though OpenType fonts can contain *many* glyphs, which also does make the font files larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the font's [EULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eula#End-user_licence_agreement) allows it, you can shrink down the number of glyphs in an OpenType font using [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Unless this site is being served over a LAN connection, using a 9MB font is ridiculous. That would force each user to be downloading a 9mb file just to view the font you use. You would be much better off picking a font that everyone has.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But question was: Is it possible to reduce font's size?

Comment: @ruth The question looks like "Large Web Font (Yes or No?)", which seems to imply "use it or not" as the question.

Answer (score 0):

www.fontsquirrel.com offers the font-face kit section that converts fonts for you - one of the choices is to have a subset of glyphs - only uppercase or just numbers. That might help to reduce the size. Typically fonts served as WOFF are below 100kb.

Comment: Thank you, but it ends with "File Size Error".

Comment: Doh, guess that 9MB is too big for it :(

Answer (score -1):

Even if you shrink the font, most users' web browsers won't download or display it.

http://www.webdirections.org/blog/the-return-of-font-embedding-to-the-web/

Comment: Any evidence for that statement?

Comment: http://www.webdirections.org/blog/the-return-of-font-embedding-to-the-web/ is a good start. If you use browser checking to distribute TTF and EOT separately then you might get a reasonable level of penetration (50%?), but never nearly enough to design your site around it.